# Should I Be Using A WebView?

Tags: javascript, webview, appcelerator

I am currently building an Android and iOS mobile app using Appcelerator/Titanium.

The app is straight forward enough - our API returns a JSON response of the latest stories, the stories and displayed in a list and when a user selects a story this is rendered.

Up until now I have been using Phonegap for our apps, so it was dead simple to simply output the HTML in the JSON response and everything worked.

Now I've moved to Appcelerator due to some limitations I encountered with Phonegap and the fact it's really just a fancy WebView. However I can't see any better way to display a stories content than in a WebView again.

For example, the API returns the complete story content as HTML and can contain pretty much any HTML tag `<p>,<strong><img src=""/><a href="">links</a><script></script><iframe></iframe>` as we tend to embed facebook,twitter posts, links, videos, graphs, iframes and inline javascript and CSS.

However it almost seems like a step backwards to me to be using WebViews again, but at the moment it seems to be a lot more practical than attempting to parse the HTML and extract elements that could be rendered as native components, most of which probably cant (embedded tweets/facebook)

I know appcelerator allows you to set HTML to the native `label` component but this only supports Android and does not cover JS or CSS. For iOS I've looked at `AttributedStrings` but again these are limited in support.

I guess I'm just looking for some re-assurance that this is the correct way to do this. I've read a lot that rendering the WebView components affects performance quite a bit, so this is why I'm so hesitant.

My other quandary is that I am struggling to capture all the clicks in the WebView. If a user clicks on an embedded tweet for example, then the app immediately becomes a full screen WebView of twitter, when really it should open in the external browser (a reason I want to move from Phonegap). Appcelerator does let you [communicate via JavaScript](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Communication_Between_WebViews_and_Titanium-section-29004919_CommunicationBetweenWebViewsandTitanium-Remotewebcontent) to handle things like this, but it doesn't work for things like embedded tweets since they are in iFrames. Surely there is a way to do this, there's countless other apps out there that have achieved what I want to do, I just feel like I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved using the webview component but taking into account some limitations:

- If you want to capture events inside the webview, it can't be remote (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView). You can use a local template in your application and retrieve the content using an API service and render the webview as local content, in this way you can capture events like clicks.
- There is some limitations to embed third-party content like twitter, facebook. You must make some "hacks" to embedded content works fine.

Comment: Thanks  @juanblo , do you have any more information on these "hacks" for embedding third party content? I find it strange how I can find no information on it, yet there is countless apps I've seen which are doing exactly what I want to do